# Puzzle on a Rubik's Cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, mechanical-puzzles, solvability, twisty-puzzles

The puzzle is as follows:

Consider a solved Rubik's cube. Apply the move sequence M2 U M2 U2 M2 U M2  (Commonly known as the H-permutation in the cubing community). Is it possible to solve the cube using only double-moves (when you do a move, you must repeat that move)?

I suspect the answer is no because the best double moves can do is swap two edges but that doesn't preserve its adjacent edges -- consider R2 U2 R2 U2 R2 U2 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

> possible.

Proof:

> One way to do it is
>  `R2 U2 R2 U2 R2 F2 R2 U2 F2 U2 R2 F2`
>
>  Another way to see it is that you can do two adjacent swaps:
>  `U2 F2 U2 F2 U2 F2`
>  and
>  `U2 R2 U2 R2 U2 R2`
>  This fixes the U layer pieces, but also does two swaps in the middle layer, leaving a 3-cycle. This 3-cycle can be solved with:
>  `U2 F2 U2 R2 U2 F2 U2 R2`

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I got the two adjacent edge-swaps but thought the 3-cycle was unsolvable since 3 was odd...